# How to make WiX custom setup items selected for install by default?

Tags: installation, wix

I have a question about WiX installers

Currently if the user selects Custom Setup, they get this screen. It defaults to having nothing selected to install, but the “Next” button is still enabled. If the user clicks “Next” when nothing is selected, the installation attempts to proceed, but encounters throws and exception. 
[image]

What I would like is for the top level item to be selected by default (and not allow deselect) or have the next button disabled when nothing is selected. Do you have any suggestions?

By the way, I do have Absent=”disallow” set on the object, so you can’t deselect it once it is selected, but for some reason it is deselected by default. 
[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [INSTALLLEVEL property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369536.aspx) and your [feature's Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368585.aspx#remarks) settings. It sounds like they're currently misconfigured.